# Which kubernetes identifiers have to be at most 63 characters?

Tags: kubernetes

Some kubernetes resources have a length limit of 63 characters (presumably because they need to be valid DNS names). Which are they?

Answer (score 4):

Those are **at least**:

- Pod names
- Service names
- The name part of a label key

```
    labels:
      example.com/environment: production                       <-- the string "environment"
```

- The label value

```
    labels:
      example.com/environment: production                       <-- the string "production"
```

- The name part of an annotation key

```
    annotations:
      example.com/image-registry: "https://hub.docker.com/"     <-- the string "image-registry"
```

- CronJob names (including 11 automatically appended characters)